# How do I either pull from or initialise and empty array atomically in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to initialize an array if it doesn't exists, while pulling from it at the same time if it does exist in one single atomic operation?

This is what I tried so far:

Consider a potential document like so:

```
{ _id: 1, foo: [1, 2, 3] }
```

If I would like to remove element `2` from `foo` I could write:

```
db.col.update({ _id: 1 }, { $pull: { foo: 2 } })
```

If I was unsure if document `{ _id: 1 }` existed up front and in that case would like to create it at the same time, I could expand the above query with `{ upsert: true }`:

```
db.col.update({ _id: 1 }, { $pull: { foo: 2 } }, { upsert: true })
```

But this would create the following document without a `foo` property:

```
{ _id: 1 }
```

If I would like to initialise an empty `foo` array, you'd think I could do like so:

```
db.col.update({ _id: 1 }, { $pull: { foo: 2 }, $setOnInsert: { foo: [] } }, { upsert: true })
```

But that will unfortunately give the following error:

```
MongoError: Cannot update 'foo' and 'foo' at the same time
```

Comment: why do you want to insert an empty array? Leave it away when upsert inserts a new record.

Comment: I have a schema that expects this array to always be present. It makes the code simpler

Comment: I don't get why you'd want to pull the value you already have. Could you show us the actual code problem you are trying to simplify with your approach?

Comment: Markus: It's common to remove elements from an array using $pull. It could for instance be an array of roles on a user document and you'd like to remove the 'admin' role: `{ _id: 1, roles: ['admin', 'editor'] }`

Comment: Markus: In my case I have an admin interface where an admin can manipulate a user by id and remove/add roles to him. If the user doesn't exist, it should be created at the same time

Comment: I think you'll have to deal with missing `foo` as well as empty `foo` in your code, unless you want another step on inserts to put in an empty `foo`.